# Django JWT token deactivate

Tags: django, rest, api, frameworks, jwt

I'm  creating an API for an android application I'm using Django Rest framework JWT token for API authentication. In perticular case, I want to deactivate the token which is activated for a particular user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWT is stateless auth which means it is not stored anywhere on server. When you send JWT token in header of request your server just check if token is valid. 
Therefore you cannot deactivate token - you can only delete it in your Andriod app. 
More on JWT [here](https://jwt.io/introduction/).

Comment: But here I also face another problem which is for single user credential user can create two tokens so how to stop this?

Comment: You cant, jwt is stateless. You can have as many tokens as you want. You can be logged in on many devices on the same time.

Comment: You can maybe set short expiration time and then you refresh your token if you want to(to expand expiration time). Therefore you could set that for some user you won't refresh token if he meets some conditions.